# A noise maker to assist with sleep

Tags: speakers

A lot of people find listening to white noise or documentaries useful for going to sleep.

I usually use my phone to do this, but the problem is that it's tempting to browse the internet on my phone.

Are there any devices that allow for different forms of white noise, or ideally can be loaded with podcasts?

Also good would be if it can double as an alarm clock,  especially an alarm clock that has a light that turns on.

Comment: Do you have a laptop or desktop?  I sometimes just go to endless Youtube and put on a video of thunderstorms. I'm sure there exists a white noise video.  Just shut the face of laptop or turn off your desktop's monitor and let the sound play.  With a  laptop you can plug it in across the room and turn up the speakers to where you can hear it but it isn't too loud.  With a desktop if it's in the same room you are sleeping, the same principle applies.

Comment: A couple of years ago, I just powered on my desktop, and slept to the noise of the fan. That only works if you're sleeping close enough to it.

Comment: Maybe you could rig something up with a Raspberry Pi and USB powered speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any white sound machine that also does alarm clock.
You didn't specify any price range so I assume we'll go for a middle range.

In this case, I'd recommend the Marpac Dohm-DS ([https://www.amazon.com/Marpac-Dohm-DS-All-Natural-Machine-Actual/dp/B000KUHFGM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KUHFGM)) which is around 50€ and has the advantage to create its own sound with an internal fan instead of only playing recored sounds. However there isn't any sound selection.

If you are looking for more than one sound, you may consider the Lectrofan ([https://www.amazon.com/LectroFan-White-Noise-Machine-Options/dp/B00JU8P8VY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JU8P8VY)) which for the same price offers 10 fan sounds and 10 white noises.

These are the two I know, you can find them inside a tiny article I just found (http://www.nosleeplessnights.com/best-white-noise-machine-reviews/), that presents also two others machines (a high end, ~100€, and a low-end, ~20€).